# Incrementing a function with two parameters with a FOR loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

Okay so the instructions are to create a function with two parameters. A start number and a increment number. The For loop is supposed to start at the 'startNum' and it is is supposed to increment a number of times (specified by the second parameter in the function). I am still new to programming and especially loops so to my understanding of them I feel that this should work. I have tried this for a day now with many different ways and can't seem to figure it out. Some suggestions would be helpful!

```
function myLoop(startNum,increment) {
  for (i = startNum; i >= increment; i++);
}
console.log(myLoop(2,14));
```

These are the official instructions for this problem:

Create a function called myLoop that takes in two parameters. 
The first parameter should represent a starting number and the second is how many times the starting number should be incremented.
Use a for loop to increment the first parameter a number of times equal to the second parameter.  Then return the modified number.

For example, if the first parameter is 3 and the second parameter is 4, the number three should be increased by one each time the for loop runs, and the for loop should run 4 times. This should return the number 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you wanted?

```js
function myLoop(startNum,increment) {
  for (i = 0; i < increment; i++){
    startNum++;
  };
  
  return startNum;
  }
console.log(myLoop(2,14));
```

Comment: This code did what it needed to do. Could you tell me why the middle shows I < increment. I believe the middle is where we tell the loop to stop. So how does this end up working if we are telling the loop to stop while it Is less than the increment parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wants to return the number, then simply the following will do

```
function myLoop(startNum,increment) 
{
  return startNum + increment;
}
```

However, there were some issues with the code you had shared, it should be

```
function myLoop(startNum,increment) {
  for (i = startNum; i >= ( increment + startNum ); i++); //observe that <= is replaced with >= and increment with ( increment + startNum )
  return i; 
}
```